React custom hook testing with vitest returns empty result
I have created a custom hook as follows:
import { getUserInfo } from '@/scripts/services/userService';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFileFilter = (repositoryFiles: any[]) => {
    let enabledFilters: string[] = [];
    let disabledFilters: string[] = [];
    const [filteredRepositoryFiles, setFilteredRepositoryFiles] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const filterFiles = async () => {
            let filteredFiles: object[] = [];
            const userInfo = await getUserInfo();

            for (const filter of userInfo.showSourceFiles) {
                if (filter.bool) {
                    enabledFilters.push(`.${filter.name}`);
                } else {
                    disabledFilters.push(`.${filter.name}`);
                }
            }
            if (enabledFilters.length === 0) {
                enabledFilters = disabledFilters;
                disabledFilters = [];
            }

            const fileExtentionsFilter = {
                include: enabledFilters,
                exclude: disabledFilters,
            };

            for (const file of repositoryFiles) {
                const included = fileExtentionsFilter.include.some(fileExtentions =>
                    file.name.endsWith(fileExtentions),
                );
                const excluded = fileExtentionsFilter.exclude.some(fileExtentions =>
                    file.name.endsWith(fileExtentions),
                );
                if (included && !excluded && !file.isDirectory) {
                    filteredFiles.push(file);
                }
            }
            console.log('works: ', filteredFiles);
            setFilteredRepositoryFiles(filteredFiles);
        }
        filterFiles();
    }, [repositoryFiles]);
    console.log('doesnt work: ', filteredRepositoryFiles);
    return filteredRepositoryFiles;
};

export default useFileFilter;

And I'm trying to create a test for it like this:
import { describe, test, vi } from 'vitest';
import useFileFilter from '@/hooks/useFileFilter';
import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import * as userService from '@/scripts/services/userService';

describe('For the useFileFilter hook', () => {
    const fetchSpy = vi.spyOn(userService, "getUserInfo");
    beforeAll(() => {
        const mockResolveValue = {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "some@email.com",
            "role": "user",
            "showSourceFiles": [
                {
                    "id": "cm4v6cj260003mpetpyicw2jm",
                    "name": "txt",
                    "bool": false,
                    "usersId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": "cm4v6cj260004mpetznm7rpj6",
                    "name": "py",
                    "bool": false,
                    "usersId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": "cm4v6cj260001mpet4z81kmcm",
                    "name": "gitignore",
                    "bool": true,
                    "usersId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": "cm4v6cj260002mpetxe6csa1j",
                    "name": "yml",
                    "bool": true,
                    "usersId": 1
                }
            ],
            "firstName": null,
            "lastName": null,
            "avatarUrl": null,
            "githubUsername": "SomeUser",
            "githubAccessToken": "a_token"
        }
        fetchSpy.mockReturnValue(mockResolveValue as any);
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        fetchSpy.mockRestore();
    });

    it('should return filtered repository files', async () => {
        const repositoryFiles = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "isDirectory": false,
                "path": ".gitignore",
                "name": ".gitignore",
                "lineCount": 161,
                "functionalLineCount": 80,
                "symlinkTarget": "",
                "branchId": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "isDirectory": false,
                "path": "Dockerfile",
                "name": "Dockerfile",
                "lineCount": 8,
                "functionalLineCount": 7,
                "symlinkTarget": "",
                "branchId": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "isDirectory": false,
                "path": "compose.yml",
                "name": "compose.yml",
                "lineCount": 18,
                "functionalLineCount": 17,
                "symlinkTarget": "",
                "branchId": 1
            },
            ...
        ]
        const result = renderHook(() => useFileFilter(repositoryFiles));

        console.log('result: ', result);
    });

When I run the test it produces an empty result:
result:  {
  result: { current: [] },
  rerender: [Function: rerender],
  unmount: [Function: unmount]
}

Please note the console.logs in the first code block. They produce these results:
doesnt work:  []
works:  [
  {
    id: 1,
    isDirectory: false,
    path: '.gitignore',
    name: '.gitignore',
    lineCount: 161,
    functionalLineCount: 80,
    symlinkTarget: '',
    branchId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    isDirectory: false,
    path: 'compose.yml',
    name: 'compose.yml',
    lineCount: 18,
    functionalLineCount: 17,
    symlinkTarget: '',
    branchId: 1
  }
]

So for some reason the test runs fine, but when it tries to update the state for FilteredRepositoryFiles by using setFilteredRepositoryFiles the sate stays empty. Even though this works fine when just using this feature outside of tests. Does anyone know why?
PS: quite new to react

You should not manipulate arrays like that in react. Let's reference the docs a bit.
Please read:

why you shouldn't manipulate local variables: 
Local variables don’t persist between renders. When React renders
this component a second time, it renders it from scratch—it doesn’t
consider any changes to the local variables.
Changes to local variables won’t trigger renders. React doesn’t realize it needs to render the component again with the new
data.


when to use local variables: 
You don’t need Effects to transform data for rendering. For example,
let’s say you want to filter a list before displaying it. You might
feel tempted to write an Effect that updates a state variable when the
list changes. However, this is
inefficient...

In this case a useMemo could be sufficient but, because there's a api call then we must use a useCallback. As we need to call useCallback we will also use useState to store the result and a useEffect to execute the operation when needed(when the repositoryFiles change):
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { getUserInfo } from '@/scripts/services/userService';

const useFileFilter = (repositoryFiles: any[]) => {
    const [filteredRepositoryFiles, setFilteredRepositoryFiles] = useState();

    const filterRepositoryFiles = useCallback(async () => {
        let enabledFilters: string[] = [];
        let disabledFilters: string[] = [];
        let filteredFiles: object[] = [];
        const userInfo = await getUserInfo();

        for (const filter of userInfo.showSourceFiles) {
            if (filter.bool) {
                enabledFilters.push(`.${filter.name}`);
            } else {
                disabledFilters.push(`.${filter.name}`);
            }
        }
        if (enabledFilters.length === 0) {
            enabledFilters = disabledFilters;
            disabledFilters = [];
        }

        const fileExtentionsFilter = {
            include: enabledFilters,
            exclude: disabledFilters,
        };

        for (const file of repositoryFiles) {
            const included = fileExtentionsFilter.include.some(
                (fileExtentions) => file.name.endsWith(fileExtentions),
            );
            const excluded = fileExtentionsFilter.exclude.some(
                (fileExtentions) => file.name.endsWith(fileExtentions),
            );
            if (included && !excluded && !file.isDirectory) {
                filteredFiles.push(file);
            }
        }

        return filteredFiles;
    }, [repositoryFiles]);

    useEffect(() => {
        //Only call when repositoryFiles has content
        if (repositoryFiles.length > 0)
            filterRepositoryFiles().then((v) => setFilteredRepositoryFiles(v));
    }, [filterRepositoryFiles, repositoryFiles]);

    return filteredRepositoryFiles;
};

export default useFileFilter;


Thanks for the clarification. This code looks a lot better. Unfortunately when I run my test the result still comes back empty. Do you maybe know why?

Only if you provide a MRE. Because i can't predict what is getUserInfo nor what you pass as repositoryFiles
